# Two-way communication between GUI and Controller classes in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

For the sake of clarity, I have simplified my program down to 2 small classes: a GUI with a single button, and a controller which turns that button blue when clicked. In order for the GUI to be able to communicate with the controller,  it has its own instance of Controller, but how do I get that controller to then communicate back to the GUI?

```
class Controller():
def buttonClicked(self):
    # btn['bg'] = 'blue' - how do I reference the button?


class GUI():
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    self.controller = Controller()
    self.btn = tk.Button(master,command=self.controller.buttonClicked())
    self.btn.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you want that `buttonClicked` method to be in a separate class instead of in the GUI class?

Comment: BTW, it's a Good Idea to use new-style classes rather than old-style. You can do that in Python 2 by making your classes inherit `object`, eg `class Controller(object):`. In Python 3, all classes are new-style.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm attempting to use the model-view-controller pattern for a school project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use another class, then you could just add `buttonClicked` to `GUI`, and then reference the button via `self.btn`.

If you need another class, then you would have to pass a reference for the main class, in order to use its attributes.

```
class Controller():
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui
    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.gui.btn['bg'] = 'blue'


class GUI():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.controller = Controller(self)
        self.btn = tk.Button(master,command=self.controller.buttonClicked)
        self.btn.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

By passing `self` to `Controller`, an instance of `Controller` can use all the variables, including the button, and edit them.

You also need to remove the call to `self.controller.buttonClicked` when defining the command for your button, which I have done in the altered code above.